# Magento 2 : Ghost Images From Magento Website are Trying To Be Loaded

Tags: magento2, image, cdn

I used keycdn to setup a cdn for my magento 2 website before I moved over to cloudflare but I'm having a strange issue ever since I made switch and I'm not sure how to fix it. You can view this error when going to my website at www.ooples.com and using developer console. The errors are also visible when you use incognito mode. That subdomain no longer exists.

[image]

Steps I have taken so far:

- Flushed Cloudflare cache completely
- Deleted local cache and cookies
- Checked magento configuration and nothing is there from before

Any ideas or pointers on what I can do to fix this?

Comment: What is your CDN set up?  Is cdnpull.ooples.com the place for the CDN to retrieve the media if it isn't cached already?

Comment: @Brett I currently use cloudflare cdn and that cdnpull subdomain was created to work with keycdn which I no longer use so that subdomain was deleted.